# How can we count total number of NOT NULL values in all the columns in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I am trying to calculate total number of not null values in all the columns in the data by creating new column to count that. As showed in below image, I want to calculate "NOT NULL COLUMNS".

What I want to achieve is I want to calculate how many total number of columns on an average are with not null in whole data.:
[image: This is just a sample data created myself. If it matches with someone, please disregard the information.]

I tried calculating manually but that was not possible because I have more than 500 columns in my real data with more than 5 million rows.
I don't have the code to show here that what I tried because all of my tries didn't work at all.

Can anyone help me how to do this in Python?

Comment: `df.notna().sum().sum()`?

Comment: `df.replace('',np.nan).notna().sum(1)`

Comment: Thanks for both the replies Quang Hoang and wwnde! It actually worked! Thanks, it was great help